# What does this comparison express?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between me and my language partner. I told her that I ate a variety of different types of meat, e.g. crododile and zebra. She then replied to me the following.

私もワニの肉は食べたことがありますが、シマウマは食べたことがありません。日本では、馬肉（ばにく）を食べるのですが、馬肉に似たような肉でしょうか。

I have problems with the second sentence. My attempt at translation:
"I also have eaten crocodilemeat, but I haven't eaten zebra meat yet. Concerning in japan, one eats horsemeat, but it (=zebra?) surely is meat that matches horsemeat."
Did she compare horsemeat to zebrameat here? I think she does, and contextwise I wouldn't have any better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 馬肉に似たような肉でしょうか。
>   (literally) Is it (=zebra's meat) meat that resembles horse meat?
>   I wonder if it's like horse meat.

- Please double-check the meaning of the verb [似る](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BC%BC%E3%82%8B).
- ～でしょうか is a question, and is different from ～でしょう without か.